# DB Design: How to link a single column to a collection of entities

Tags: design, database, mysql, orm

I have a db design question that I am sure has been quite extensively covered but I cannot find a good answer already.

The problem is how to efficiently link a single school course to a collection of textbooks, a course may have 0 books and it may have 10. The problem here is that multiple courses can use the same textbook as well.

My first thought was to include the textbook tables PK as a FK in the courses table. Then the courses table has a composite PK of course id and textbook id. The problem with this approach is that the courses table could potentially have a lot of columns, and then I am repeating the entire course row for every textbook addition, in addition to having to set a fake textbook_id for courses that do not have a textbook.

**courses**

- course_id
- course_name
- FK textbook_id
- PK(course_id, textbook_id)

**textbook**

- textbook_id
- textbook_name

My next thought was to have a table that has 10 columns for textbooks, that I use for linking a course to all the textbooks. But, I'm not sure if there is a better approach (this will end up using less space), when I think about this I think why not have textbook1, textbook2 columns in the courses table in the first place.

**courses**

- PK course_id
- course_name
- FK textbooks_ids

**course_textbook**

- FK course_id
- FK textbook_1
- FK textbook_2
- FK textbook_3
- FK textbook_4

**textbook**

- isbn
- textbook_name

A bit of background as well, using MySql, Hibernate ORM, and writing a separate search indexer.

Anyone have any suggestions on a better approach or thoughts on which of these two approaches is better?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are certainly getting close with your last thought. When you start to think about "a class could have at most ten textbooks," you're complicating the problem more than you need to.  Instead of having multiple columns for the `course_textbook` table, stick with one for textbook and one for course. This is a many-to-many mapping, and that's exactly what you want: the ability to pick any course, and find every book it uses, or pick and book, and find every course it uses. Typically, in database design, we care about only three conditions: 0, 1, and many. Your `SELECT` statement would then join on the table, returning multiple rows if there are multiple books.

Comment: So your saying the course_textbook table has two columns both of which are FK (textbook_id and course_id), then the PK is a composite of both?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. The table with two FK is what you should use to model the many-to-many relation

Comment: Nice, thanks for the input. The only problem I see with this approach is that if you know the course name and want to get all the textbooks, you have the query the courses table to get the course_id to then query the courses_textbooks to get all the textbooks. But there is always a trade off.

Comment: @user1944367 That's exactly right. You have to query more tables, which happens any time you normalize a database (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). However, that's something a database engine is incredibly good at doing, so it shouldn't be too much of a concern (unless performance proves otherwise).